# Estimate Oracle Database Size

Tags: oracle

I have a total of 50,000 records with each row has 20 columns of a combination of character, date, and numeric fields. I need to estimate how many mega bytes of database space Oracle will require for table, indexes, and other considerations such as block size.

Could you please help.

Thanks so much!

Go my answers. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you really concerned about a few mega bytes? I would recognize your question if you would say "... total of 50 billion records" I think the Oracle system tables will occupy even more space.

Comment: The installation size of Oracle will probably be bigger than a tiny table with 50k rows

Comment: Hi, I don't have a reply option to REPLY.  I'm trying to size a future Oracle Database that the total records may go above 365,000,000. Each Row may have 1000 Characters. I need to size the table, index, and PCT % increase if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check view `USER_SEGMENTS`, there you see data size (column `BYTES`) for tables and indexes. Take these values and divide by 50'000, then you get the average size per row and you can estimate the total size.

I think 50'000 rows as sample size should be fine. If the sample is too small then your estimation would be poor.

Nowadays you typically use Locally Managed Tablespaces where `PCTINCREASE` does not apply. For block_size use default `8K`. Don't waste so much effort for such little data.